# Montar una sitio html a un servidor iis

Tags: html, iis

Como puedo montar una carpeta que tiene documentos html a un servidor iis?
solo agregue el sitio pero no me deja ver la pagina.

Comment: que versión de IIS estas usando?

Comment: version 7 mi estimado!

Answer (score 1):

Te falta asignar la carpeta virtual como "Web Application" y configurar el Application Pool. Por otra parte, habilitar extensiones si en algún momento requerís subir cosas de ASP.NET.

Si por otra parte ya está creado lo que te digo, probablemente, si tenés algo ocupando el puerto 80 como el WAMP, APPSERV deberás cambiar el puerto de escucha.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero sigue sin funcionar, Me aparece como "Host not found" ya agregue una carpeta virtual, y el apache es el que corre en puerto 8080, asi que el iis tiene el 80 por default.

Comment: La carpeta, ¿La creas en C:\inetpub\wwwroot?. ¿Tenés corriendo el motor? o sea... si el Web Application esta iniciado o Stoppeado. ¿Estas usando un nombre de página por defecto?, si no lo estas usando deberías ponerle index.html o default.aspx segun corresponda, si no aparece, deberías configurar en el IIS para que admita el nombre de los archivos. ¿Cual es el error?

Comment: La carpeta la cambie a documentos/mywebsites, no esta detenido, aparece como corriendo, si el nombre la pagina por defecto es index.html
creo que tengo que configurar lo ultimo que me conta, CONFIGURAR el iis para que admita ese tipo de archivos, como?

Comment: http://thumbs.subefotos.com/d92d7e730ccc8f376245bdefd6d84ecdo.jpg
http://thumbs.subefotos.com/a9663720194d16c379fb8cf6ba41c985o.jpg
http://thumbs.subefotos.com/fc9762bfda58c91373abe91ea24dc3a9o.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Puedo darte algunos tips para poder crear un sitio y que este funcione pero antes debes asegurarte de lo siguiente:

- El puerto que deseas utilizar no debe estar en uso
- Si estas montando tu servidor en tu pc de escritorio para probar, asegurate de que skype no está bloqueando el puerto 80, sino puedes usar un puerto 8080 para probar

  Como configurar tu sitio web:
- Abre IIS
- Despliega el arbol de servidor principal
- Presiona botón derecho en sitios y elije la opción agregar nuevo sitio
- Escribe un nombre de sitio descriptivo
- Deja el grupo de aplicaciones llamado "DefaultAppPool"
- Escribe la ruta correcta a donde están los html en la sección de ruta de acceso física
- Tipo de protocolo http
- dirección de IP Alguna que desees asignar
- Puerto, debe ser uno que no esté en uso
- Nombre del host, escribe una web ficticia, por ejemplo misitio.com
- Dejar tildado Iniciar sitio web inmediatamente
- Presiona aceptar

Abre un notepad como administrador en el caso de que estes usando windows y luego abre el siguiente archivo :
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Luego en la ultima linea escribes algo como lo siguiente:

{IP ELEGIDA DESDE IIS}  dominio.com

Remplazar por el valor o IP real que fue añadida en el IIS sobre el sitio que creamos dominio.com

Si sigues los pasos tal cual podrás hacerlo sin problemas.

Espero que esto les ayude.

Saludos!